# Material autocomplete load data on value changes with http call

Tags: angular

In my angular 4 application I have some material autocomplete inside a FormGroup, I want to search (making an HTTP call) only when user write something in the autocomplete field.
So I am following this example: 
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/autocomplete-force-selection-tests-csip5w?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

But in my case I need to make a remote call to retrieve the info so I have to call a service:

**Service.ts**

```
  getCustomers(name: string) {


    return this.endPointUrlService.checkIfMapIsReady(this.entityLink[2])
      .flatMap((res) => {
        return this.http.get(this.endPointUrlService.cutLinks
          (this.endPointUrlService.mapNames.get('customersSearchMap').get('autocompleteWithWallet')), { params })
          .map((response) => <Customer[]>response);
      })
  }
```

As you can see my service returns an observable of `Customer[]`

So how can I make it works in the component?
Or more generally how can I make the call on value changes?

Comment: why dont you use async pipe ?

Comment: already have it, but I want to make the http GET call only on value changes

Answer (score 1):

**Component:**

```js
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

customerControl = new FormControl();
matchingCustomers = new BehaviorSubject<string[]>([]);

ngOnInit() {
  this.customerControl.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    this.customerService.getCustomers(val).subscribe(customers => {

      this.matchingCustomers.next(customers);

      // OR (depends on where you want do filtering [component|service|server]):

      // this.matchingCustomers.next(customers.filter(customer => {
      //   return customer.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      // }));

    });
  });
}
```

**Template:**

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="customerControl">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of matchingCustomers | async" [value]="customer">
            {{ customer }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

In the **Service** I would do some checks to prevent redundant HTTP calls. 
Something like this:

```js
// optimizations possible

private lastSearchQuery: string = '';
private cachedCustomers: Customer[] = [];

getCustomers(name: string): Observable<Customer[]> {
  if (name.length > 2) { // developer defined value to prevent large responses
    // first search || 'name' is not part of 'lastSearchQuery'
    if (this.lastSearchQuery == ''
      || this.lastSearchQuery.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
      this.lastSearchQuery = name;
      return this.http.get<Customer[]>('https://example.org/customers?q=' + name).map(customers => {
        this.cachedCustomers = customers; 
        return customers;
      });
    } else { return Observable.of(this.cachedCustomers); }
  } else { return Observable.of([]); }
}
```